# How can a workflow B be triggered from a workflow A after it clompleted?

Tags: argo-workflows, argoproj

I have two workflows A and B. How can workflow A trigger workflow B after completion without having to introduce a third workflow chaining A and B (f.x. using steps or dag)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumable you can use an exit handler for this?